# ENOENT error when using Forever-Agent

Tags: node.js, request, http-live-streaming

I have the following case:

```
var request = require('request');
var ForeverAgent = require('forever-agent');
var agent = new ForeverAgent();

request("http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/wowzaid3/playlist.m3u8", {agent:agent}, function(err, response){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(err);
});

request("http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/wowzaid3/playlist.m3u8", function(err, response){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(err);
});
```

In the first request block I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: connect ENOENT /adaptive/wowzaid3/playlist.m3u8]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/adaptive/wowzaid3/playlist.m3u8' }
```

While the second without forever agent returns a response as expected.

Any help understanding what I maybe doing wrong in such a case would be appreciated.